# Jetpack Compose: How to Provide Context for Dagger/Hilt

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

So I realized when testing my actual app that I still need to provide a `Context` (when running actual tests I just used `val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext` so I just kinda forgot about it.

But now I'm running the actual app in the emulator and get this error on startup: `error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

My DI object looks like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideShotTrackerDatabase(context: Context): ShotTrackerDbAdapter {
        val db = ShotTrackerDbAdapter(context)

        return db.open()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideShotTrackerRepository(db: ShotTrackerDbAdapter): ShotTrackerRepository {
        return ShotTrackerRepository(db)
    }
}
```

Of course my ViewModel is pretty standard, here's the declaration:

```
@HiltViewModel
class FirearmsViewModel @Inject constructor (private val shotTrackerRepository: ShotTrackerRepository) : ViewModel() {
```

I guess I kinda assumed this would already be provided since it's easily accessible in a Composable via `LocalContext.current`, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `application: Application`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideShotTrackerDatabase(application: Application): ShotTrackerDbAdapter {
     val db = ShotTrackerDbAdapter(application)
     return db.open()
}
```

Or `@ApplicationContext context: Context` as you already found:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideShotTrackerDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ShotTrackerDbAdapter {
     val db = ShotTrackerDbAdapter(context)
     return db.open()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

However while writing this question I stumbled upon the answer. You use the `ApplicationContext` annotation in front of your `Context`:

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideShotTrackerDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ShotTrackerDbAdapter {
        val db = ShotTrackerDbAdapter(context)

        return db.open()
    }
```